Finding the function with power series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^n}{n^2}$
I want to evaluate the power series $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^n}{n^2}. $$
I am getting that $f(x)$ is equal to some integral of $\dfrac{\ln(x+1)}x$, which is not elementary integrable.
I don't get it. Did I make a mistake? Or is it that the power series can not be written as a composition of elementary functions on some interval.

No error there, it is called the dilogarithm, more precisely $-\operatorname{Li_2}(-x)$, it is indeed a non-elementary function.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Polylogarithm.

As Zwim said in the comments, there are many special functions which we didn't see in ordinary calculus classes. One of them is $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$ which is used in many posts of MSE. It is defined by
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=\int_0^{x}\frac{-\ln(1-t)}{t}dt.$$
So, we have
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)=\int_0^{-x}\frac{-\ln(1-t)}{t}dt.$$
Make the substitution $t=-u$. Then,
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)=\int_0^{x}\frac{-\ln(1+u)}{u}du.$$
That is,
$$\int_0^{x}\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}du=-\operatorname{Li}_2(-x).$$
I think this is the sum of your power series which satisfies the diferential equation $(xy')'=\frac1{1+x}$.
